# XMLHttpResponse payload different from XHR.responseText

Tags: jquery, excel

Goal: Download a dynamically created XLSX file from a server.
Issue: The `XHR.responseText` in the `$.ajax success` function is not the same as the `XMLHttpResponse` as viewed from the DEV tools Network tab. (Using Firefox 62.0.3 64bit, Go Lang to create the document, and jQuery 3.1.0 to manage the AJAX response)

If the DEV tools content is copied into an `<a href>` tag, then the file downloads correctly.

```
<a download="excelTest.xlsx" href="data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8;base64,UEsDBBQAC....CAAgAAKxUAAAAA">Download file</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/amoedwzL/

However, if the same anchor is set programmatically with the `XHR.responseText` value, I am given a broken Excel document.

```
<a id="downloader" download="excelTest.xlsx" href="">Download file</a>
var responseText = "PK\u0003\u0004\u0014....\u0000\u0000\u0000"
document.getElementById("downloader").href = "data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8," + responseText
```

http://jsfiddle.net/amoedwzL/1/

The example Excel document should have 1 worksheet titled "Stackoverflow" with the A1 cell containing the text "test".

Comment: If it isn't clear, I want to either be able to copy the unadulterated response, or, find a different way to download my file. I am not tied to any one given solution.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the Firefox Network tab was displaying the equivalent of the Chrome Network Tabs Preview screen. Chrome displayed the same thing, but also showed a non rendered version as well. A coworker was able to come up with a fix below, shown below.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.onload = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE) {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            //Create anchor to hold the data for download
            var a = document.createElement("a");
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.style = "display: none";
            url = window.URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);
            a.href = url;
            a.download = "excelDocument.xlsx";
            a.click();
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        }
    }
};
```

This is what was previously handling the servers response is shown below.

```
$.ajax({       
    method: "POST",
    dataType: "script", //This was changed to blob, to no effect
    url: url,
    data: d,
    success: function(data, status, xhr){
        if (xhr.status == 200){
            callback(data); //Sets href value, nothing special happens here
            return
        }

        App.handleError(data, status, xhr);
    },
    error: function(data, status, xhr){
        console.error("Error " + data.status + ": " + data.statusText);
    },
});
```

It appears that something involving jQuery was the culprit, but we are unsure precisely the cause.